# How can I return customizing headers in hyper? Rust

Tags: rust, hyper

What I want to do is return custom headers in hyper (but return them and return the response body as well) For example, I'm going to take the code from the [hyper documentation](https://hyper.rs) as an example:

```
async fn handle(_: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, Infallible> {
    Ok(Response::new("Hello, World!".into()))
}
```

For example, this code only displays `Hello World!` on every request, and always returns a `200` status code. But for example, How can I send other types of custom headers? What I tried was to use `Response::builder` instead of `Response::new` (as you can see in my example I use `::new`, what I tried separately was to use `::builder`) but it gave errors since that type of data cannot be returned. So how can I return the header I want and as many as I want but keeping the "body"?

Comment: Could you please show your code that used `Response::builer` and what errors did you got. This seems to be a correct way of solving your problems. Maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your idea of using [`Response::builder`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.20/hyper/struct.Response.html#method.builder) seems to be correct. Note however that it returns a [`Builder`](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.8/http/response/struct.Builder.htm), which method [`body`](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.8/http/response/struct.Builder.html#method.body) must be later used to create a `Response`. As `body`'s documentation states:

> “Consumes” this builder, using the provided body to return a constructed Response.

A working example of setting custom headers of a response (how many you like) you can see in the documentation of [`Builder::header`](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.8/http/response/struct.Builder.html#method.header). It looks like this:

```rust
let body = "Hello, world!";

let response = Response::builder()
    .header("Content-Type", "text/html")
    .header("X-Custom-Foo", "bar")
    .header("content-length", body.len())
    .body(body.into())
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: When executing the exact code you give me and returning it with `Ok(response)` I get this error: `expected struct Body, found &str`

Comment: @New1 Fixed. I forgot to call `into`.

Comment: Thank you very much, no more error. I'm really going to give you the reward because you replied to the main topic (I'll give you the bounty in 5 hours since I can't give it to you yet because 24 hours haven't passed). But with my actual code what I do is create the `Response::builder()` and lines later I add the headers, but I add them individually, and that gives me this error: `expected struct hyper::Response, found struct hyper ::http::response::Builder`. Just as extra help (obviously optional, since you already answered the main topic of the question) do you know how I could solve it?

Comment: @New1 Hi. If you would like more help We can talk here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249155/rusts-hyper-library